# How do I apply an explicit lifetime bound to a returned trait?

Tags: iterator, rust

Returning an iterator from a function in Rust is an exercise of Sisyphean dimensions, but I am told it's possible to return one as a trait without quite so much pain. Unfortunately, it isn't working: apparently, I need an explicit lifetime bound? Which is apparently not the same thing as adding a lifetime parameter. Which means I have no idea how to do that.

Here's my (tiny, test) code:

```
fn main() {
    let args = get_args();

    for arg in args {
        println!("{}", arg);
    }
}

fn get_args() -> Iterator {
    std::env::args().filter_map(|arg| arg.into_string().ok())
}
```

What is the appropriate way to make this actually *work*?

Edit: rust version rustc 1.0.0-nightly (00df3251f 2015-02-08 23:24:33 +0000)

Comment: To alleviate this issue partly, you are encouraged to provide the version of the compiler you are using, and if using nightly the date and commit ID. This way, it makes it clear to future onlookers that the question and answers might not be applicable to them any longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return a bare `Iterator` from a function, because it is a trait, thus not a sized type.

In your situation, you'll need to put the iterator object inside a box, in order to make it into a sized object that can be returned from the function.

To do so, you can change your code like this:

```rust
fn get_args() -> Box<Iterator<Item=String> + 'static> {
    Box::new(std::env::args().filter_map(|arg| arg.into_string().ok()))
}
```

Here I've added a lifetime specifier `'static` for the trait object, meaning that it is completely self-owned (a function taking no arguments will almost always return something valid for the `'static` lifetime in this sense).

You also need the `<Item=String>` part to explicit the type of data yielded by your iterator. In this case: Strings.

Comment: Ok, just curious: can you explain why the syntax for the Iterator trait isn't the standard GenericTypeThing<OtherType> syntax I'm used to?

Comment: @archer884 it's an associated type. A type associated with the trait that is defined by the implementation, and not arbitrarily decided by the user. Sadly, the documentation about theses is still very lacking.

Comment: oh! Also, is there a downside to using 'static vs. using a generic like 'a?

Comment: @archer884 you can't use a generic lifetime `'a`, because it can't be linked to any input lifetime as your function doesn't have any input. `'static` is the only possible choice here.

Comment: @archer884 If you want to learn more about associated types, you can have a look at the RFC introducing them : https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/195

Comment: Actually, fn get_args<'a>() -> Box<Iterator<Item=String> + 'a> { ... will also compile and run. Is that bad?

Comment: Probably not bad. I think the value of `'a` is simply inferred by the compiler to be `'static`.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case you can manage to return a concrete type from your get_args, like so:

```
fn get_args() -> FilterMap<Args, fn(OsString) -> Option<String>> {
    fn arg_into_string(arg: OsString) -> Option<String> { arg.into_string().ok() }
    args().filter_map(arg_into_string as fn(OsString) -> Option<String>)
}
```

basically this applies to all the cases where the closure you use in the iterator adapter (in your case filter_map) is not really a closure, in that it does not capture any environment, and it can be modeled by a plain old function.

In general, if you do need to return a type that does contain a closure, you will indeed need to box it and return a trait object. In your case:

```
fn get_args() -> Box<Iterator<Item=String> + 'static> {
    Box::new(std::env::args().filter_map(|arg| arg.into_string().ok()))
}
```

Comment: I know it's possible to do that. The problem is that it's just not practical for many (maybe even most?) of the actual iterators I use. Hence this little sample and my attempt to figure out how to avoid those painful type signatures.